# "In a while" vs. "soon"

Tags: idioms

I am getting very confused because my girlfriend is using the idiom *in a while* really often and it sounds weird every time (we are both non-native speakers). She would say for example "I am going to leave in a while" or "I will sleep in a while", when she means *soon* or *in a couple of minutes*. I fell like something is weird since I cannot recall hearing any native speaker use this idiom to express the same thing. I can absolutely be wrong, but my girlfriend has a history of translating greek straight into english, which leads to some funny use of words :)

Any proficient english speaker wants to clarify when and how they would use *in a while* - if at all - in a casual context?

Comment: "In a while" is used quite often in casual speech.  It is tricky, though, to use the phrase with clarity, especially since it can mean "in two or three minutes" or "in a year two" -- it's important for the context to convey this.

Comment: "In a while" is usually used to indicate an unspecified time, likely a short time, but not definite. It would indeed be maddening to hear this instead of "soon". The long version of "in a while" would be "eventually" meaning for certain but but in the distant future.

Comment: "in a little while" tends to be closer to "soon". Adding "little" indicates that the indefinite time will not be very much long.

Comment: They're both nebulous. When your partner calls you in to dinner, and you respond, "in a while", or "soon," could mean five minutes or, eventually, an hour... and the foods been overcooked.

Comment: To me, "in a while" means a longer time from now than "soon". I only use it to mean "at some time, not right away". When comparing "*See you in a while*" with "*See you soon*", I expect the first one to be a longer time than the second one.